# My segue is not executed after taking a pic

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app which uses a camera and then the photo is supposed to be sent to another ViewController, but i'm not sure if it maybe the segue is not be able to there or that it is just be executed, but when I confirm the photo my app crashed and no errors are showed on my log.

This is the camera View controller

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController , 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

var img = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func photo(_ sender: Any) {
    checkCameraPermissions()
}


private func checkCameraPermissions() {
    let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        print("1")
        presentPicker()
    case .notDetermined:
        print("2")
        askPermision()
    case .denied:
        print("3")
        // user denied access
        self.permissionDenied()
    case .restricted:
        print("Error restricted")
    }
}

private func presentPicker() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        img.image = pickedImage
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "captured", sender: nil)

}

private func askPermision(){
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) {granted in
        if granted {
            self.presentPicker()
        } else {
            print("Denied")
        }
    }
}

private func permissionDenied() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Access to camera is denied", message: "You have denied the access to the camera. Would you like to able it?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.askPermision()
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Cancel")
    }
    alert.addAction(actionOK)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated : true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "captured"){
        let vc = segue.destination as! ImageReportedVC
        vc.imgAux = img.image!
    }
}
}
```

And then, this is the 2nd VC which doesn't appear. I believe the segue shouldn't be done there or something, but if you put it in another part of the code, it is executed before taking the photo.

```
import UIKit

class ImageReportedVC: UIViewController {

var imgAux = UIImage()


@IBOutlet weak var imgReported: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imgReported.image = imgAux
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



 }
```

Thanks

Comment: post the crash log ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss the picker

```
picker.dismiss(animated:true) {  
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "captured", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: the other question has a crash may be op fixed it and encounter another issue